# How to fix automatic bigint generation in spring boot for table column

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

I have a spring boot application with two entities in a relationship. MeetingSetting and MeetingTime meetingSetting can have unlimited meetingTimes. So far the databases are generating without problem and I can halfway save the values as well. But there is one problem. meetingName is a string and used as a foreign key in meetingTime but when the database are generated for some reason it is added as a bigint and I could not find the reason for that, because everywhere it is used as string. Could someone look at my code and tell me my mistake?

MeetingSettings:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_settings")
@Data

public class MeetingsSetting {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "meeting_name", unique = true)
    private String meetingName;

    @Column(name = "meeting_url")
    private String meetingUrl;

    @Column(name = "meeting_pw")
    private String meetingPw;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "meeting_Name", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<MeetingTime> meetingTime = new HashSet<>();
}
```

MeetingTime:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "meeting_times")
@Data
public class MeetingTime {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "meeting_date")
    private String date;

    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private String startTime;

    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private String endTime;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_name" ,insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private MeetingsSetting meeting_Name;
}
```

This is my application property:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/coorporate_blinddate?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true&useSSL=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.properties.javax.persistence.schema-generation.scripts.create-target=../generate.sql
spring.jpa.show-sql= true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.datasource.driver-class-name= com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=Test1234@@1
server.port=8081
```

and the script used for db generation:

```
-- auto-generated definition
create table meeting_settings
(
    id           bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    meeting_name varchar(255) null,
    meeting_pw   varchar(255) null,
    meeting_url  varchar(255) null
);

-- auto-generated definition
create table meeting_times
(
    id                  bigint auto_increment
        primary key,
    meeting_date        varchar(255) null,
    start_time          varchar(255) null,
    end_time            varchar(255) null,
    meeting_name        varchar(255) null,
    constraint fk_meeting_times_meeting_name
        foreign key (meeting_name) references meeting_settings (meeting_name)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this with the big int by adding referencedColumnName = "meeting_name" to this in meetingTime:

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_name" ,insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private MeetingsSetting meeting_Name;
```

changed to:

```
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "meeting_name" ,insertable = false, updatable = false, referencedColumnName = "meeting_name")
    private MeetingsSetting meeting_Name;
```